# How to send push notification when var1 == var2 in Swift?

Tags: arrays, swift, apple-push-notifications

I am writing a simple timer app in SwiftUI, but I can't figure out how best to send completion push notifications. I have a countTo variable, which is the number of seconds scheduled, and a counter variable that keeps track of the current second.

Considering the user can pause, play and end the timer, what would be the best way to send a notification once countUp == counter? I can't schedule a set time because that doesn't account for pausing and playing. Would it involve cancelling the notification and then rescheduling it when the user resumes the timer?

Thanks for any help, much appreciated!

Comment: Please clarify your question by adding some relevant code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably you're talking about local notifications. Push notifications are sent via APNS and the app can't send them.

For local notifications, look into `UNNotificationRequest` and different triggers (`UNNotificationTrigger`).

It looks like the `UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger` will work best for your task. When the user pauses the playback or the playback gets interrupted by the system, you'll have to cancel an existing notification and then schedule another one once the playback is resumed.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I mentioned this in my answer - a UNNotificationTrigger seems to only take a date as a parameter. Would this involve amending the date if the user pauses and resumes the timer?

Comment: `UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger` takes not a date but rather a time interval. Once you add a notification request to the notification center, you can't amend it. However, you can cancel a pending request. so once your user unpauses the playback you need to remove the previous request and add a new request in order to reschedule the notification.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can refer to this documentation.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/scheduling_a_notification_locally_from_your_app